# Can I get a photo of an Ancient Arrow?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've been building up my photo album, and I have photos of almost everything, save a few enemies, a weapon or two, etc.

But I was wondering if it is possible to get a photo of an Ancient Arrow? I don't think I've ever seen an enemy drop them, I've only received them from chests or from purchasing them from the Lab, and you cannot hold or drop arrows. Is it possible?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. [This guide](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75271919) describes a few options, and the easiest way looks to be to fire the ancient arrow into a body of water. The arrow will float and you can snap the picture

[image: Ancient arrow in river]

Answer (score 4):

You can also shoot an ancient arrow into the wall behind the shrine elevator. It falls to the floor intact.