# What things do I only get a limited opportunity to take photos of?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In BotW, the compendium requires you to take photos of each and every monster, creature, weapon, shield, etc. at least once. This does include unique items, like the Heroes' weaponry (Sword of the Seven, Radiant Trident, etc); The Blight Ganons; and I recently noticed the Sand Seal that Riju uses during the Naboris chase is also unique.

What are all the items, creatures, weapons, etc that I only get a limited opportunity to take a photo of?

Comment: I think you can buy the pictures you missed out on.

Comment: @CyberSkull yes that is an option, but I want to try and get everything without purchasing them, at least once ;)

Comment: Patricia, Raiju's Sand seal, is normally kept in a pen in Gerudo town in the southeast wing of the palace, and you can photo her at any time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some spoilers, from what I can recall:

- The master sword before you pull it out (you can always take a selfie later but it won't be in the rock anymore)
- All the base game bosses (blights, divine beast, Master Kohga, and ganon)
- The bow of light used at the end boss (You have to take a selfie with this one I think)
- All the DLC special enemies and the one hit obliterator (I think you can repeat the challenge to get more pictures?)
- According to [the wiki](https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Permanently_Missable_Items#Breath_of_the_Wild): in Masters Mode you can possibly miss the Lynel Crusher, Mighty Lynel Crusher, and Lynel Spear as the enemies scale out of using those weapons.
- <s>Ancient arrows (there's only a few places where you can find one laying around or in a breakable item)</s> ([see comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/352572/222207))

Note, if you do take a picture of the item you will never be able to buy the compendium version that's on sale, which may be of a better quality (like the bow of light).

Comment: It sounds like [ancient arrows may not actually be as hard to capture as you think!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/352572/222207)

Comment: @scohe001 nice, that would've never occurred to me

Comment: About the blights, if you have the Champion's Ballad DLC, they are not really missable as you can fight them again however often you want.

Comment: You don't need to be in Master Mode to miss the Lynel weapons. What the wiki actually says is that you can miss *fewer* weapons in Master Mode.

Comment: Are there any "one time" creatures like Riju's sand seal as well?

Comment: If you have the Champion's Ballad, you can take a picture of the Master Sword in the Trial of the Sword pedestals.   You can take a photo of the Bow of Light rotating in the air and save it to your compendium any time you refight Dark Beast Ganon, no selfie necessary. The One-Hit Obliterator remains for photo-ops in the Shrine of Resurrection at any time after you complete the challenge. All the DLC enemies can be refought/rephotoed at any time.

Comment: The Bow of Light doesn’t need to be a selfie. You can jump off the horse before you pick up the bow.

Comment: Riju's Sand Seal is in it's own pen in gerudo town, and you can give it fruit, but it will just scam you. RARELY, will it give you advice.

Answer (score 6):

Building on [||'s answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/352715/92731), information on the Breath of the WIld Object Map, and my own experience in filling the Compendium with pictures taken of objects in the game, below are the permanently-missable Compendium Photos in Breath of the Wild.

**Creatures**:

- There are no creatures that disappear permanently from the game.

**Monsters**:

- Guardian Sentries -- These only appear during the quest to board Vah
  Rudania. If you don't snap them during your climb, you'll never see
  them again.
- Cursed Bokoblins  -- I might be wrong on this, but I've *never*
  encountered them outside of a Divine Beast. When I've gone looking
  after having completed all the Divine Beasts, all the Malice Mouths I
  could find only spewed Cursed Moblins and Cursed Lizalfos.
- The Blight Ganons (Thunderblight, Waterblight, Windblight, and Fireblight) are inaccessible after their respective Divine Beasts are completed, unless you have the Champion's Ballad DLC.
- Master Khoga cannot be refought, even with the DLC.

**Materials**:

- There are no materials that disappear permanently from the game.

**Equipment**:

- The Lynel Crusher, Lynel Spear (Normal Mode Only), Mighty Lynel Crusher, and Mighty Lynel Spear eventually are removed from the game as nearly all of the Lynels go Silver or higher.
- The Kite Shield is only found in chests, and as a Minigame Award.  Open all the chests and win the one on the cabin wall in Selmie's Shield Surfing, and they'll all be gone.

**Treasures**:

- There are no treasures that disappear permanently from the game.

Comment: Cursed Skulls of all enemies can also be found in Hyrule Castle.

Comment: @EgorHans At the time I wrote the referenced answer, I'd gone to Hyrule Castle after having defeated all the Divine Beasts,  and spent twenty minutes at each Cursed Skull-spewing Malice Mouth I could find. They only spewed Cursed Moblins and Cursed Lizalfos, never a Cursed Bokoblin to be seen.

Comment: Weird, I definitely saw some Boko skulls somewhere. Thinking about it more thoroughly, it might've been one of the Lynel arenas.

Comment: Counterside update though: After you defeat Kohga, all Yiga grunts change their weapon. I don't remember seeing the old one anywhere.

Comment: @EgorHans At least, according to the  [Breath of the Wild Object Map](https://mrcheeze.github.io/botw-object-map/), three unchested Vicious Sickles can be found in the valley leading to the Yiga Clan Hideout, two look like they're atop stone pillars.

Comment: Confirmed all three. There are two Vicious Sickles inside the Yiga Clan Hideout post-Khoga, and one on a stone pillar at the entrance to the valley.