# Are pictures of the Elemental arrows (fire, ice) required for the full compendium?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I have been working on completing the Hyrule compendium. However, I am worried about getting a picture of the Elemental arrows, because I cant seem to get one! It would require insane timing to catch a snap of one with the camera!
Are the Elemental arrows required for the compendium, or am I just freaking out?

Comment: Related: [Can I get a photo of an Ancient Arrow?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352572/can-i-get-a-photo-of-an-ancient-arrow)

Comment: In a newer update, Ancient arrows do not break on non-hits anymore. Useful, but makes that question redundant for my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are required; the five special arrows are entries 349 through 353 in the Compendium (354 to 358 in Master Mode).  You don't need to photograph them while they're flying through the air, though.  Among other options, you can photograph them while they're lying on the ground or a table in a shop that sells them. [The "Slippery Falcon" shop in Tarrey Town](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/wiki/Tarrey_Town#Slippery_Falcon_.28Tarrey_Town_Branch.29) would be ideal for this.

Comment: I forgot about that shop! Thank god I finished Tarry town. ;D